# faster fractions module in python

Tags: python, fractions

Is there a faster equivalent of the `fractions` module, something like a `cFractions` module, just as there is a `cDecimal` module, which is a faster equivalent of the `Decimal` module ? The `fractions` module is too slow.

Answer (score 6):

I was struggling with lack of this package as well and decided to implement one called [`cfractions`](https://pypi.org/project/cfractions/) (source code available [on Github](https://github.com/lycantropos/cfractions)).

The only thing we need is to install it

```sh
/path/to/python3 -m pip install cfractions
```

and after that replace `fractions` with `cfractions` in your modules, as easy as that.

Main features include

- less memory

  ```
  >>> from cfractions import Fraction
  >>> import sys
  >>> sys.getsizeof(Fraction())
  32
  ```

  compared to

  ```
  >>> from fractions import Fraction
  >>> import sys
  >>> sys.getsizeof(Fraction())
  48
  ```

  so it's basically a plain Python `object` + `2` pointers for numerator & denominator.
- more speed:

  - construction from pair of `int`
    [image: construction from pair of integers]
  - construction from single `float`
    [image: construction from single float]
  - construction from `str`
    [image: construction from str]
  - sum of `n` instances
    [image: sum of n instances]
  - product of `n` instances
    [image: product of n instances]
    or if we take a look at relative performance
    [image: relative product of n instances]
    we can see `fractions.Fraction` skyrocketing, yay!

  **Note**: I'm using [`perfplot` package](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot), all benchmarks run on `Python3.9.4`.
- `Python3.5+` support,
- plain Python C API, no additional dependencies,
- constructing from numerator/denominator pair, single `int`/`float`/any `numbers.Rational` value, `str` (from [version `1.4.0`](https://pypi.org/project/cfractions/1.4.0)),
- full spectre of arithmetic & comparison operations,
- string representation (both `__repr__` & `__str__`),
- `pickle`ing and `copy`ing,
- immmutability & hashability,
- operating with `int` and `float` (with conversion of `Fraction` instance to `float` for the latter, as it is for `fractions.Fraction`),
- `PyPy` support (by falling back to `fractions.Fraction` proxy),
- property-based tests of all operations using [`Hypothesis` framework](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis).

What it doesn't include

- operating with `complex`.

Answer (score 4):

Use http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/

It uses the GMP mutliple-precision library for fast integer and rational arithmetic.

Note: I'm also the maintainer.

Comment: It looks amazing -- is there a way to have a Fractions class in gmpy2 that works like the mpr but supports the __repr__ and other features of fractions.Fraction? I'd love to be able to do conditional import -- if gmpy2 exists then "from gmpy2 import Fraction" else "from fractions import Fraction"?

Comment: `cDecimal` was designed to be an exact replacement for `Decimal` so using the same name made sense. The `mpq` type in `gmpy2` tries offer the same capabilities as the `Fraction` type but it uses the real type name for `repr`. Since `gmpy2` can't be included with Python for licensing reasons, I plan to keep the names distinct. You could write a simple wrapper class that changes the formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't realize the licensing differences.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no c equivalent available without needing a compiled external dependency. Depending on your needs, the gist I've made: https://gist.github.com/mscuthbert/f22942537ebbba2c31d4 may help.

It exposes a function `opFrac(num)` that optionally converts an int, float, or Fraction into a float or Fraction with a denominator limit (I use 65535 because I'm working with small fractions); if the float can be exactly represented in binary (i.e., it's a multiple of some power of two denominator), it leaves it alone. Otherwise it converts it to a Fraction. Similarly, if the Fraction is exactly representable in binary we convert it to a float; otherwise we leave it alone.

The `Fraction(float).limit_denominator(x)` call is extracted out into a helper function, `_preFracLimitDenominator`, that only creates one `Fraction` object rather than the three normally created with the call.

The use cases for this gist are pretty few, but where they exist, the results are spectacular. For my project, music21, we work mostly with notes that are generally placed on a beat (integer) or on a half, quarter, eighth, etc. beat (exactly representable in binary), but on the rarer occasions when notes have placement (offset) or duration that is, say, 1/3 or 1/5 of a beat, we were running into big floating point conversion problems that led to obscure bugs.  Our test suite was running in 350 seconds using floating point offsets and durations. Switching everything to Fractions ballooned the time to 1100 seconds -- totally unacceptable. Switching to optional Fractions with fast Fraction creation brought the time back to 360 seconds, or only a 3% performance hit.

If you can deal with sometimes working with floats and sometimes Fractions, this may be the way to go.

Comment: The problem of `limit_denominator` creating two extra Fraction objects (with gcd called for each) has been mitigated in Python 3.11 beta.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything.
You could make one.http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html

A quick search on fractions in c gave me http://www.spiration.co.uk/post/1400/fractions-in-c---a-rational-arithmetic-library. Use the 2nd post, it also handles negative numbers.

But that may not be what you need and you can find something else. If you don't want to extend python you have to stick to Fractions if you can't find anyone who has a cFractions module. I'm sorry.

Comment: Making one is not easy it seems because I don't know how would I handle arbitrarily long numbers in C as we do in python. Same problem with the second link - it works only as long as the numerator and denominator are just within 4bits (or 8 bits at the max).

Comment: Okay, I'm not that good at math :P I just gave you some that I found ;)